# how can i fix the cannot find symbol error

Tags: java

```
public class ListQueue extends LinkedList {
  public ListQueue() {
    super();
  }

  public boolean empty() {
    return isEmpty();
  }

  public void enqueue(Object item) {
    addToTail(item);
  }

  public Object dequeue() {
    return removeFromHead();
  }
  public int size(){
    return super.size();
  }
}

// class ListQueue
```

> ListQueue.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
>   return super.size();
>               ^
> ```
>
> symbol: method size()
>   1 error

Comment: `.java` ... so, nothing to do with javascript at all - tag with right language you may get the right people to help :p

Comment: It is working. Can you send your whole class ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the fixed solution:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ListQueue extends LinkedList {
  public ListQueue() {
    super();
  }

  public boolean empty() {
    return super.isEmpty();
  }

  public void enqueue(Object item) {
    super.add(item);
  }

  public Object dequeue() {
    return super.removeFirst();
  }
  public int size(){
    return super.size();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to the imports section of the class:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
```